# argument.callee.name alternative in the new ECMA5 Javascript Standard

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm working on porting some old code to 'strict mode', what are the alternatives to the argument.callee and similar argument.caller etc in the ECMA5 standard?

---

ADDED INFO: I did not specify why I need the argument.caller/callee.

The code I'm porting is using

```
assert.ok(elemNode, arguments.callee.name + ": Entity - " + entityId + " has been found");
```

If it were simple recursion I could use function name(){ ... function() ... }, but I can't seem to find what to do with the above code.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Thanks for pointing that out, Added usecase for my problem, the problem I'm trying to solve is not the same as the one solved in that question.

Comment: Can you include the rest of your unit testing logic? I need more scope to work with here. That one liner isn't giving me any base of reference. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with ECMAScript 3, you can have named function expressions.  Prior to that function expressions were anonymous, which made `arguments.callee` necessary.    Named function expressions made it unnecessary.  So that's the recommended alternative.

See [the MDN docs for callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee)

#### Example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map(function factorial (n) {
    return !(n > 1) ? 1 : factorial(n-1)*n;
});
```

#### The benefits of named functions (from the MDN docs):

- the function can be called like any other from inside your code
- it does not pollute the namespace
- the value of this does not change
- it's more performant (accessing the arguments object is expensive)

Answer (score 3):

Not really.

There is no way to mimic or "*polyfill*" the `arguments.caller` property, that has been removed for *security reasons*, so you can't climb up the scope chain, in-code.

The best alternative for `arguments.callee` is to just to have named function expressions, instead of anonymous function expressions, like

```
setTimeout(function loop() {
    if( /* condition */ ) {
        loop();  // instead of arguments.callee();
    }
}, 1000);
```

That is also faster in almost all implementations (accessing the `arguments` objects is somewhat slow'ish in general)

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your function and then just reference the function by that name.

Comment: Please refer to the edit! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent, strictly speaking. As John Resig [points out](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/), you need to name your "anonymous" functions in ECMAScript 5's strict mode and then you can call them directly. His example is:

```
setTimeout(function later(){
  // do stuff...
  setTimeout( later, 1000 );
}, 1000 );
```

Comment: John Resig's blog was the first place I looked for what needed to be done, I looked at Mozilla's developer documentation next, but none of them seem to have an alternative. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode